# How to build Universal url using js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deep-linking

Currently, I use Firebase deep link, And now I don't want to use Firebase anymore, so I need to implement deep link by myself,

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a platform, but in browser, [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class is part of the browser API.

You can use it to alter URLs or parse them, for example:

```
  const test = new URL("http://example.net");
  console.log(test.href) // http://example.net/
  test.protocol = "https";
  console.log(test.href); // https://example.net/
  test.pathname = "myfile.html";
  console.log(test.href); // https://example.net/myfile.html
```

It does require you to specify some valid URL as a starting point though, but you can then change every part of it to whatever you need.

For example, if you wanted to get an absolute link to another file on your domain on frontend, you could do:

```
var url = new URL(location);
url.pathname = "anotherfile.html"
url.hash = "someanchor"
console.log(url.href) // https://stackoverflow.com/anotherfile.html#someanchor
```